# While swapping two values, the input of the function must be two const pointers and the return should be void

Tags: c, pointers

I've written the code for passing the values normally with pointers My question is how to pass these values i.e. a & b as constant pointers, if it is not already.

```
void swap(int *x, int *y) 
    {
       int tmp;
       tmp = *x;
       *x = *y;
       *y = tmp;    
       return;
    } 
     
int main () {

   int a = 20;
   int b = 12345;
 
   printf("Before swap, value of a : %d\n", a );
   printf("Before swap, value of b : %d\n", b );
   swap(&a, &b);
   printf("After swap, value of a : %d\n", a );
   printf("After swap, value of b : %d\n", b );
 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can make them constant pointers to non-constant data; since you're swapping the values they point at, you can't make them pointers to constant data.  That means you can use `void swap(int * const x, int * const y) { … }` without changing the body of the function.

Comment: Why do you need to make them constant pointers?

Comment: @DanielWalker Presumably because a homework problem is testing understanding of the C syntax, or a style guide is encouraging the practice of slapping `const` on everything except things intended to be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` in C generally goes *after* the type, and the `*` is part of the type, so the type declaration of an integer pointer constant is:

```c
int * const
```

You may have tried `int const *`, and found that to not work. That's because, to repeat, generally `const` applies to the thing on its left.

Opinion: This is why I hate the pattern of writing `const` first, like `const int`. It only works because the language has a special case - if there is nothing to the left of the `const`, it applies to the thing on its right - and since most people learn by example, every occurrence of `const` at the beginning of a type declaration contributes to mis-teaching people trying to learn the language.

Tip: I like reading and saying `const` as "which is constant", because that phrase clearly refers to the thing before it, so it matches the left-to-right order of the parts of a type declaration: `int const` then reads as "an integer which is constant" and `int * const` reads as "an integer's address which is constant".

Putting that together with your `swap` function we get

```c
void swap(int * const x, int * const y)
```

Opinion: This is also why I dislike `*` in a declaration "touching" the name. I do `int * foo` instead of `int *foo` because it's more consistent with other type declarations like `int * const foo`, which I feel is more important than consistency with the unary operator placement in dereferences like `*foo`.

But you should know that in C, or at least in all real and most conceivable implementations of C, it doesn't actually change code behavior to make function parameters `const` like that - the parameter itself is private to the function, so the function can't change it. The only way it could realistically make a difference for the actual code is if you had a C compiler which could better optimize a function if you tell it that it won't be modifying its own parameters, but most optimizing compilers can just notice if a parameter isn't being modified within a function. Of course, it can still be useful as a way of telling people reading your code what your intent with the parameters is, and if you have a habit of declaring things const any time you don't have specific intent to change them, you're more likely to have computers catch certain mistakes (like if you have a parameter named similarly to a variable in your function, and you mean to modify one but accidentally type the other - if the other was `const`, simple tooling can catch the mistake).

Comment: Re “the `*` is part of the type”: It is not, actually; it is part of the *declarator* in a C declaration, not part of the *type-specifiers* or the *declaration-specifiers*. This is why `int * a, b;` declares `b` to be an `int`, not an `int *`, because the `*` is grouped grammatically with the `a`, not with the `int`. You will find the grammar for declarations in clause 6.7 of the 2018 C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, and I'll upvote your comment to help it be more visible for the people who would benefit from it, and I'll give it a think to see if I can word it better, but I'd say that's a higher level of pedantry than appropriate for someone still asking this kind of question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Like, in a very true sense, a "pointer to int" is a type in C, and `int *` is a way to refer to that type in the C language. So calling the `*` part of the type is something I consider a reasonable gloss/simplification/smudge, a way to maximize how much truth is conveyed with plain language and few words - without detours into orthogonal concepts and distinctions and details. Even in C discussion, it can be more helpful and informative to use words like "type" in their freer, plainer sense, and I think this is one such case.

Comment: The statement about `*` is discussing the syntax and parsing of a declaration, not the semantics of types. The syntax and parsing are dictated by the grammar, which is clear. This “reasonable gloss” gives students false ideas about the language, causing them difficulties later.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments are passed by value, and values are not `const` or non-`const`; only objects can be qualified that way. You can qualify the function parameters (which are objects that are initialized to the argument values), and that just means the function will not change the values of the parameters:

```
void swap(int * const x, int * const y)
{
    // x and y are not changed, although the objects they point to are changed.
    int temporary = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temporary;
}
```

If you want to make the parameter types pointers to `const` objects, that is also possible. As long as a pointer points to an object that was not defined with `const`, the behavior of removing the `const` through a conversion and using it to modify the object is defined:

```
void swap(const int *x, const int *y)
{
    /* ncx and ncy are set to the original pointers to non-const
       that became the pointers to const that are x and y.
    */
    int *ncx = (int *) x, *ncy = (int *) y;
    int temporary = *ncx;
    *ncx = *ncy;
    *ncy = temporary;
}
```